# Finding the matrix of a permutation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

I am studying inverse permutations and I was given the following permutation sequence:

25413

I attempted to convert this permutation sequence into a permutation matrix:

[image]

I thought this was correct, but my book says that the permutation for 25413 is actually matrix A (which I thought was actually the inverse permutation matrix):

> The permutation 25413 is represented by the 5x5 matrix A

[image]

I thought the permutation 25413 was represented by the matrix B. Can someone explain why 25413 is represented by matrix A?

Comment: Could be an issue on whether you consider matrix vector multiplication using row vectors (with matrix on right) or column vectors (with matrix on left).

Comment: There are two ways of defining a permutation matrix. Yours is called row representation, while your book uses the column representation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix

Comment: I don't know what book is that but it undoubtedly doesn't use permutation matrices the way I do. For me, the cycle $\;(25413)=(13254)\;$ would be represented by the permutation matrix$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$which means: row 1 to row 3 to row to row 2 ...and etc. I thought for a moment it goes according to columns, but nop...so I've no idea.

Comment: @DonAntonio When the book says $25413$ it actually refers to the permutation that transforms $(1;2;3;4;5)$ into $(2;5;4;1;3)$ ; so the permutation is actually $(12534)$.

Comment: @krirkrirk Now that makes sense, thanks. Would have never guessed...and they even go by columns! Amazing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$25413$ is presumably shorthand for 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}

meaning that the position filled by element $1$ is subsequently filled by element $2$, etc., so your matrix needs to fulfill

$$A\cdot  
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\ a_4 \\ a_5  \end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2 \\ a_5 \\ a_4 \\ a_1 \\ a_3  \end{pmatrix}
$$

Which is fairly obviously achieved by the row-swapped version of the identity matrix, and (perhaps less obviously) is undone by the column-swapped version.